# how do I apply Style to a Blazor input element

Tags: css, input, blazor

```
<InputCheckbox class="input-checkbox100" id="ckb1" style="background: #918f8f;" name="remember-me" @bind-Value="CurrentCustomerSubmission.AcceptedTermsAndConditions" />
```

however when the component is rendered, the color that is being displayed is from the class (input-checkbox100). I am trying to override it for this 1 specific element (so not trying to add it to the CSS).

Comment: "so not trying to add it to the CSS". Why not? `#ckb1 { background: #918f8f; }`...

Comment: my manager told me not to do that...

Comment: Oh, managers :).

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: Add a unique class to the input instead of using an id? See if the manager buys that?

Comment: What isn't working? You can definitely use an inline style attribute like you have for background

Answer (score 0):

You can use style tag in your blazor component and override your css class

for example :

```
@page "/"

<style>
.input-checkbox100{
    background: #918f8f;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a name to your class here i set ForInput:

```
<InputCheckbox class="input-checkbox100 ForInput" id="ckb1" name="remember-me" @bind-Value="CurrentCustomerSubmission.AcceptedTermsAndConditions" />
```

then go to wwwroot go to css and then open app.css and add ForInput in your css with your desire background.

```
.ForInput{
    background: #918f8f;
}
```

Comment: So... I had been using regular HTML nodes in Index.razor, and I could put the CSS's in Index.razor.css. But it seems for Blazor's `<Input...>`, the CSS in Index.razor.css does not work and I need to put it in `wwwroot/css/site.css". Why is it so?